# How to slide a container on user click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to javascript and I have my sign up and login screen setup I want it to slide when users click on sign up or login but my index.js is giving me errors any way to fix that, or am I implemented it wrong?

Login screen:
[image: Login screen]

My code:
[image: my error]

Comment: First try with your bare hands, 2nd post your error when you **try** to do some codding

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $("div").animate({
          left: '250px'
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <button>Start Animation</button>

  <p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>

  <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery then you can add class/ID.slideToggle(), this will do the trick

try with below reference url: [w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation1](http://w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/…; 
    <script> 
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("button").click(function(){ 
          $("div").animate({left: '250px'}); 
        }); 
      }); 
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
    <button>Start Animation</button> 
    <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:‌​absolute;"></div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: how do  i add JQuery?

Comment: try with below

reference url: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation1




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>

<button>Start Animation</button>

<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

</body>
</html>